# Pass a class, instantiate it and and use the right method

Tags: java, generics, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a wrapper method for sending a Get request:

```
public CloseableHttpResponse sendGetWithHeaders(String url, Map<String, String> headers) {

    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

    // loop over entrySet() and httpget.setHeader(key, value);

    return client.execute(httpget); // client instantiated elsewhere
}
```

It works.

But I don't want to create another 5+ almost identical methods for `Head`, `Put`, `Options`, etc.

Can I generify this method by passing in a Class? Meaning

```
sendRequestWithHeaders(HttpGet.class, "url", someMap)
```

The below attempts fail:

```
CloseableHttpResponse sendRequestWithHeaders(Class<?> clazz, String url, Map<String, String> headers) {

    Object request = clazz.newInstance();
    // request.setHeader(key, value); doesn't compile because it's of type Object
}
```

or

```
<T> CloseableHttpResponse sendRequestWithHeaders(Class<T> clazz, String url, Map<String, String> headers) {

    Object request = clazz.newInstance();
    T t = clazz.cast(request);

    // setHeader(key, value); doesn't compile either because T is generic
}
```

P.S. I have an alternative solution using Apache's `RequestBuilder` anyway, I'm just interested if there is a solution for the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request classes for `Get`, `Post`... extend `HttpRequestBase` so you can limit `T` accordingly:

```
public <T extends HttpRequestBase> CloseableHttpResponse sendRequestWithHeaders(Class<T> clazz, String url, Map<String, String> headers) throws IOException {
    CloseableHttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        HttpRequestBase request = clazz.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(url);
        if (headers != null) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> header : headers.entrySet()) {
                request.setHeader(header.getKey(), header.getValue());
            }
        }
        response = client.execute(request);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // handle exception
    }
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. Note: you may want to edit your answer to `return client.execute(request);`

Comment: Thanks for the hint, didn't expect client to be of type `CloseableHttpClient`, so I slightly changed to code.

Comment: How do you set the entity?

Answer (score 2):

For the exact described case, you may want to use a factory function (`Function<String, HttpRequestBase> requestFactory`) and method references (`HttpGet::new`, `HttpPost::new`, etc.) to achieve the desired result.

Please consider the following draft implementation using Apache HttpClient 4.5.3:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (final CloseableHttpResponse response = CustomHttpClient.sendRequestWithHeaders(
            HttpGet::new,
            "http://apache.org/",
            new HashMap<>())) {
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
            final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            final String bodyAsString = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            System.out.println(bodyAsString);
            EntityUtils.consume(entity);
        }
    }

    private static class CustomHttpClient {
        private CustomHttpClient() {
        }

        public static CloseableHttpResponse sendRequestWithHeaders(
            final Function<String, HttpRequestBase> requestFactory,
            final String url,
            final Map<String, String> headers) throws IOException {
            final CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients
                .custom()
                .setDefaultHeaders(createHeaders(headers))
                .build();
            return client.execute(requestFactory.apply(url));
        }

        private static Collection<Header> createHeaders(final Map<String, String> headers) {
            return headers.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(entry -> new BasicHeader(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, jCoder was first and his solution is simpler. But +1 for the handy `createHeaders()` util method, I will definitely use it.

Comment: @Andrey, please note that the approach, proposed here, is compile-time safe: if the constructor with the single string parameter does not exist, there will be a compilation error.

Comment: True that. But since `T` is limited to `HttpGet()`, `HttpPost()` etc., which are Apache's library classes, I will go with the risk that they won't get rid of the constructor that takes a string in the near future :)